# Mclaurin series and n-th derivative

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

(1) Find the general formula of the Maclaurin series of $f(x) = \arctan((x^3)/2)/x^3$.

(2) Evaluate the 18-th derivative of $f(x)$.

(3) Evaluate $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} f(x)$.

By general formula do we just write the formula for Maclaurin series with the $n$-th derivative? Kind of lost on how to handle Maclaurin series when not in the form on $1/(1-x)$. Would also appreciate general tips on dealing with these.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider the series of $$\tan^{-1}(y)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} y^{2n+1}$$ Replace $y$ by $\frac{1}2x^3$ and divide the resulting expression by $x^3$.

Comment: I'd like to get some intuition for doing these problems in general, how did you realize to do this?

Comment: It is almost the same trick every time. Find the simplest series, change variable and so on. If you search on this site, you will find many problems solved that way. Moreover, may I confess that I felt in love with Taylor series more than sixty years ago ? So, I suppose I acquired some intuition in this area. Cheers.